# More than one macro in Private Sub Document_Open()?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm a bit confused about how the `Private Sub Document_Open()` works. I understand you have to place it in the "ThisDocument" area. But what if I want to place 3 or 4 macros there? Can you do that? And if yes, how do you do it? Because I also understand you cannot use the same sub name in two macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Macro1
    Macro2
    Macro3
End Sub

sub Macro1()
'do stuff
End Sub

sub Macro2()
'do stuff
End Sub

sub Macro3()
'do stuff
End Sub
```